# Static properties | Relationship to 'this' and 'self'

Tags: php

Why is a static designation requierd to make this interpret correctly?  See comment in code below.

```
<?php

require_once 'class.database.php';

class table extends database
{   
    static protected $_args=array(); // static added here to remove error   
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        self::protect();
    }
    function protect()
    {
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
        {
            self::$_args[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        $i++;
        }
    }
```

.
.
.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: What's the error and can you post the code?

Comment: Edit your question to add the code instead of posting a comment. Indent each line with four spaces. Highlighting the code block and pressing Ctrl+K does this automatically. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **class properties** and **object properties**. Class properties belong to the class itself, not an instance, are declared with `static`, and are accessed with `self::`. Object properties belong to an instance of the class, are declared without `static`, and are accessed with `$this->`.

You can access a class property from an object method, if you use `self::`. But you'll be accessing the same property that other instances access.

You can't access an object property from a static method, of course, since there's no object/instance involved.